# Running protractor with phantomjs

Tags: selenium-webdriver, gruntjs, jasmine, phantomjs, protractor

I am trying to resolve the error I am getting while trying to run protractor test with phantomJS.

```
Exception thrown: Keeping the Selenium server alive
ERROR - Unable to start a WebDriver session.

/Users/test/projects/test/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/error.js:113
var template = new Error(this.message);
             ^
UnknownError: org.openqa.selenium.browserlaunchers.Proxies
```

Versions I am using are:

```
{
   'phantomsjs': '1.9.16',
   'selenium-server-standalone': '2.44.0',
   'protractor': '1.7.0',
   'jasmine-reporters': '2.0.4',
   'grunt-protractor-webdriver:'0.2.0'
}
```

My protractor configuration files is:

```
exports.config = {
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

baseUrl: 'http://localhost:9000/',

"capabilities": {
    "browserName": "phantomjs",
    "phantomjs.binary.path": require("phantomjs").path,
    "phantomjs.ghostdriver.cli.args": ["--loglevel=DEBUG"]
},

specs: ['../test/e2e/**/*.js'],

// Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.
jasmineNodeOpts: {
//onComplete: false,//use function to teardown database and rebuild etc....
    isVerbose: false,
    showColors: true,
    includeStackTrace: true
}
};
```

My grunt task configuration looks like:

```
protractor: {
   e2e: {
            configFile: "config/protractor.conf.test.js"
        },

        run: {}
},
```

And I registering task as:

```
grunt.registerTask('test', function () {
    grunt.task.run([
        'build',
        'browserify:spec',
        'karma:unit',
        'protractor_webdriver:start',
        'protractor:e2e'
    ]);
});
```

I was able to run configuration with chrome, but phantomjs keeps failing.

Comment: I read a comment by one of the Angular team members saying that Phantom isn't really all that suitable for Protractor testing. There are just too many irregularities and issues with the DOM rendering to fully rely on it.  I've only used Chrome for Protractor although I do use PhantomJS for unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

This article has some good details on the problems with PhantomJS and the solution if you can use Linux in some way (perhaps via Docker or Vagrant) http://tobyho.com/2015/01/09/headless-browser-testing-xvfb/

From the article

> Although it is built on top on WebKit - the same rendering engine both
>   Safari and Chrome use, it still behaves in subtly different ways from
>   those browsers, which can cause false positives (tests failing when
>   there is not a real defect) and in some cases performance degradation
>   of your test suite. Since PhantomJS isn't a real browser in the sense
>   that no end-user actually use it, fixing these issues specifically for
>   PhantomJS becomes an upkeep cost of the test suite, rather than
>   something that directly improves the product.